# Long Press Gesture Recognizer Interfering With Scroll in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having trouble adding a long press gesture to my UITableView. Well, technically, I do have a long press gesture recognizer, but I set the minimum taps duration to 0.08. I did this because I want to have the same general action for tapping and holding down a cell, but the action only changes based on how long the cell was held. Anyway, here is the code where I add the gesture recognizer (in `viewDidLoad`) :

```
    var longPress:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.08
    longPress.delegate = self
    longPress.cancelsTouchesInView  = false
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(longPress)
```

In my `handleLongPress()` function, I get the CGPoint where there was a long press and then get the tableView cell from that.

So basically, if I scroll quickly, (like if I flick the screen), the table view scrolls fine. If I try to scroll slowly, the long press event fires and I can't scroll.

All I want to do is to be able to scroll slowly, I want the tableviews default scroll gesture to override any long press.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ScrollViews have a `panGestureRecognizer` property, you can call `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` on your long press recognizer with the scrollView's panGestureRecognizer as an argument and it will only fire if the pan gesture in the scroll view fails.

Comment: That fixes the issue, but now the long press is failing no matter what. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can do it the other way around, tell the scrollView's recognizer to fire only if the long press fails.

Answer (score 0):

This category might solve your problem:

```
@interface UITableView (CellSwipeAdditions)
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
@end

@implementation UITableView (CellSwipeAdditions)
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
        return YES;
    }
@end
```